# First web server questions

Tags: webserver, bandwidth, mail-server, nameservers

Just looking for some help/suggestions with this. I require my own server for an upcoming project that will be hosting users websites. I want to build a control panel the user can log into and modify their website which will be stored elsewhere on the server. This all seems easy enough, It's just managing domains and emails that confuse me.

What should I look for to manage domain names and point them to the correct website and also what would be the best way to manage email accounts/set up new ones etc. I want to avoid cPanel/WHM if possible, I'm looking to control most things through the control panel I will be building. So any suggestions on this would be useful as well, as I will be wanting to add email accounts through php (Can be done using a shell I assume?).

I will also be wanting to measure bandwidth used on the websites contained in each users directory, any suggestions on making this possible?

I'm really looking for some suggestions on what software to use to set this up, any advice would be really helpful!

Thanks,
Graeme

Comment: Maybe serverfault.com -- but even still it seems broad. I can only recommend you reasearch DNS and Email servers, typically these are provided by your web hosting company. When you roll your own server, you need to host these yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I'll head over there. I'm looking to run my own server, but WHM/cPanel is not appropriate for what I'm looking to do, so it's leaving me left figuring out how to do things without it!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've got a lot of creative room. May I suggest a web framework? [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com). With it you can build out a nice control panel, it's template system is clean and concise. It's also based on Python and thats why I suggest it. If there is a python module for it, you can use it in Django... so things like altering, creating, etc. local data/files is a breeze. you simply us Python (you can even forget it's "django"), crunch your data and then spit it out (into django... out to templates.. to display to the user).

You'll likely want AJAXY biznazz, their is a nice Django App for that, [Dajax](http://www.dajaxproject.com/). Django has a rich and helpful community and tons of resources. Just hop on GitHub.com and search for Django, You'll find tons of stuff.

Im building a DNS Control Panel with it. Which sounds like a minimal version of what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for that, I haven't really looked at Django but I'll look into it and see what can be done!

Comment: *highly* recommend it. I swore off web development a few years ago and then I was introduced to Django. I now make a living working on Django projects. It made me love web dev again. I think Ruby (or Ruby on Rails) is the closest thing to it but I never got into it.